.NET Framework project works with .NET Framework dll but not the .NET Standard version
I'm referencing a dll (that I took from the .NET Standard directory of a certain nuget package (which is Aspose.Drawing)) in my .NET Framework project, and some of the functionalities show errors and don't work. This is the message I get when I try to compile the project:

Error CS1069 The type name 'Color' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing'

The project won't build. But when I reference the exact same dll in a .NET Standard project, it works fine and there is no compile time error.
Isn't it that a .NET Standard dll should work with any target framework types? I want to know, how the exact same dll works differently in different targeted framework projects? Is it has to do anything with built-in functionality of system.drawing in .NET Standard projects?
To solve this, I referenced the .NET Framework version of the package in my .NET project, and it did work fine, but the problem is, because of our third party handling system, I only can add one dll that all our projects would reference. So I wanted that all our projects to reference the .NET Standard version.
Any help would be appreciated.

It is defined in the Aspose.Drawing.Common package.  Be sure to add a reference to it.
